# Exclude Items in a foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, which contents are shown by a foreach. This is my Code:

```
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
  if ($result->getdayOfWeek() != 5 || $result->getdayOfWeek() != 6):
    echo $result->getdayOfWeek().'<br>';
  endif;
}
```

I want to exclude Itmes where `$result->getdayOfWeek()` is 5 oder 6. The way I have it does not work.

Comment: By convention people don't use `if: ... endif;` in normal code. Instead they use `if { ... }`. The alternative control structure syntax is reserved for templates and should be used only there.

Answer (score 6):

You need an and (&&) instead of an or (||).

```
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
  if ($result->getdayOfWeek() != 5 && $result->getdayOfWeek() != 6):
    echo $result->getdayOfWeek().'<br>';
  endif;
}
```

You could also do it the following way:

```
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
{
  if ($result->getdayOfWeek() == 5 || $result->getdayOfWeek() == 6):
    continue;
  endif;
  echo $result->getdayOfWeek().'<br>';
}
```

Also, as nikic mentions, the convention is using braces for your if statements:

```
  if ($result->getdayOfWeek() == 5 || $result->getdayOfWeek() == 6)
  {
    continue;
  }
```